# Why can a private property be accessed outside the class?

Tags: php, oop

So I have a simple class that contains a property and a method. I don't understand why the private property of my class can be outputted outside of that class. Can anyone make some light on this? I read that it a private property can't be accessed outside of its class.

Why I don't get an error on the next code?

```php
class simpleClass{
    private $property = 'TEST';
        public function show_property(){
          echo $this->property;
        }
}

$my_object = new simpleClass();
$my_object->show_property();
```

Comment: As i know you have access the private variable in public function so, it is accessible.

Comment: I thought that if the property is private, even though the method is public it can be accessed only in that class by the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *property* may be private but you have also created a *public* function which has access to the property. This function `show_property()`, being part of the class itself, actually *has* access to the private parts of the class.

The comment you made shows a slight misunderstanding of the situation:

> I don't understand why the private property of my class can be outputted outside of that class.

You're right, it cannot be accessed outside of the class. It can only be accessed *within* the class. However, by calling `show_property()`, you have actually *moved* into the class (temporarily).

Comment: I thought that if the property is private, even though the method is public it can be accessed only in that class by the method.

Comment: @Ionut: yes but what you seem not to realise is that it *is* only accessed in that class.

Comment: Ok. So what I understand is that the public method provides flexibility to a property, no matter how is defined(public, private, static, etc). Am I right?

Comment: @Ionut, yes, basically. A public method can be used to access a non-public data item. It greatly helps with encapsulation since you can change the internal data as much as you want without having to change client code, provided the API (getters/setters) change alonside the internals.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not accessing the property from outside the class at all.

You're calling the `show_property()` method, which is public so you're allowed to call it. `show_property()` in turn is accessing the private property, but that's also OK, since that is *not* an access from outside of the class.

The point of having a private property and a public accessor / getter method is exactly this - you have control over how and whether at all your private property may be accessed.

Comment: I thought that if the property is private, even though the method is public it can be accessed only in that class by the method.

Comment: Slight nitpick, though I also made the same mistake. Technically it's not really a getter, since it doesn't actually *get* the private item (or a copy of it) to give to the caller. It's more of a "printer" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Hah, you're right, missed that. I'll leave it there though as it applies to private properties and public getters in general.

Comment: Ok. So what I understand is that the public method provides flexibility to a property, no matter how is defined(public, private, static, etc). Am I right?

Comment: Defining a property private allows you to prevent direct access to it from outside the class. You then can use public methods to let the outside of the class access the property in the way you desire (e.g. only for reading).

Answer (score 0):

It is not accessed outside. Outside means $myobject->property.

Answer (score 0):

Make function as private.

```
class simpleClass{
    private $property = 'TEST';
        private function show_property(){
          echo $this->property;
        }
}

$my_object = new simpleClass();
$my_object->show_property();
```

Comment: I thought that if the property is private, even though the method is public it can be accessed only in that class by the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what you ask. You dont acces the private object $property. Instead you acces the public function show_property() which resides inside the class simpleClass. So the object $property is still private. because both the function and the object are in the same class, the function can acces the object.

If you would try to echo the object from $my_object, you would fail to do so because the object is private.